# How do I see a list of ALL official game avatars in Steam?

Tags: steam

On the site and in the steam client it lets me see all of the avatars up to the letter "C". It cuts off at "Castle Crashers". How do I see the rest of the game avatars? I want to go to the next page and see the D games, and the E games, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not possible at the moment.

You might want to report that to Steam for a solution.